# C++ Static Property

Tags: c++, static, properties

I am having issues accessing a static property in a class. I am getting the following error:

`shape.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class TCollection<class Shape *> Shape::shapes"`

The definition of the class is:

```
class Shape {

public:
    static Collection<Shape*> shapes;

    static void get_all_instances(Collection<Shape*> &list);
};
```

And the implementation of the static method being:

```
void Shape::get_all_instances(Collection<Shape*> &list) {
    list = Shape::shapes;
}
```

It seems like the `shapes` property isn't being initialized.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick feedback. Took hours to research and about 1 minute on StackOverflow.

Comment: I think you will very much regret both having a static variable as well as having a public variable. Do you really need that? Why don't you simply pass a const Collection<Shape*>& object wherever you need a list of all shapes? This will encourage other developers to call Shape::get_all_instances() whenever they need the list, instead of passing it explicitly. This will lead to all sorts of problems, when you want to test or you want to operate on sublists of shapes.

Comment: Yeah it's public at the moment because of furious debugging.

Comment: That Furious Debugging guy rarely is a good design advisor. `:)`

Comment: Good thing it's for an assignment :)

Comment: I hope you mean a custom "Collection" class and not the System.Collections.ObjectModel::Collection<T>. Well, probably yes, this would not compile otherwise...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're right since static variable are only declared within class and not defined.

You *must* define them too, just add following line into the file where is your implementation.

```
Collection<Shape*> Shape::shapes;
```

And It should do the trick.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. You need to add

```
Collection<Shape*> Shape::shapes;
```

in one of the .cpp files to define the static member.

Answer (score 6):

You have declared `shapes` but haven't defined it.

Add the definition to the implementation file

```
Collection<Shape*> Shape::shapes; //definition
```

Answer (score 4):

the declaration is in the class.

the definition must be placed in exactly one cpp file:

```
Collection<Shape*> Shape::shapes;
```

Answer (score 4):

For the code as-is you need to provide a definition of `shapes`, like (in an implementation file)

```
Collection<Shape*> Shape::shapes( whatever constructor args );
```

But instead you might want to consider a member function that returns a reference to a local static `Collection<Shape*>`.

Cheers & hth.